# trigger form submit after changing a form value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

When I click the Next Page button (marked as >> in form), I am able to change the value of the form input in jquery. But am unable to get the Form Submit to be called after that.

I have tried the following 4 ways:

```
1. $("form#submit").submit();
2. $("submit").submit();
3. $("#submit").submit();
4. $("form:first").submit();
```

The jquery and html form code is listed below. Could you look and point out what mistake I made? Thanks a lot.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.urlParam = function(name){
var results = new RegExp('[\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
if (results==null){
   return null;
}
else{
   return decodeURI(results[1]) || 0;
}
}   


$("#reset").click(function(){
$("#semail").val("");
$x = $.urlParam('id');
$("#all").load("contactlist.php?id=" + $.urlParam('id'));
    //$("#all").load('contactlist.php?id=1');
    event.preventDefault();
    location.reload(true);
});

$("#nextpage").click(function(){
$page = $("#spage").val();
var newValue = parseInt(parseFloat($page)) + 1;
$("#spage").val(newValue);
$("form#submit").submit();

});
});
</script>
```

Form HTML is

```
<form name="search" id="search" action="/projects/mauto/contactlist.php" method="GET">
Email: <input type='text' id='semail' name='semail' size="50" value=''>
Page: <input type='text' id='spage' name='spage' size="3" value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'>
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" value="Search Enquiry">               
<input type="button" id="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">
<input id="nextpage" type="button" value=">>">
</form>
```

Comment: the form has an id=search not submit so you should do $("form#search").submit(); or just $("#search").submit();

Comment: Thanks Lelio. I have tried both again, now. But it did not trigger the form submit... Any other clue?

Answer (score 0):

try

`$("form#search")[0].submit();` instead of `$("form#search").submit();` and try calling `ev.preventDefault()` in the event before that.

Comment: Thanks. I have now tried each one below... but no luck
`code`
         //$("form#submit").submit();
 //$("form#search").submit();
 //$("#search").submit(); 
 event.preventDefault();
 $("form#search")[0].submit();

Comment: can you create a plunker and reproduce this?

Comment: Thanks. I have created it at https://plnkr.co/edit/idd0YvSCrf19VYGNm78O